# Structuring a multi-language project?

Tags: python, code-organization, project-structure

I'm working on a project which involves writing code for multiple devices, each in its own language (in particular, Arduino and Python). I want to contain the entire project in a single directory, but I'm not entirely sure what the best way to organize the project is. Currently, I'm working with this:

```
.
├── Arduino
│   └── ArduinoServerSRC.ino
├── Docs
│   └── adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino.pdf
├── Libraries
│   └── F310_Gamepad_Parser-master (borrowed from github, has subdirs)
│       └── [dirs and things]
├── Old Versions (may replace with "Prototyping" folder)
│   └── somecode.py
├── PC
│   └── Python
│       ├── code.py
│       └── Tests
│           └── blank.py
└── README.md
```

In particular, I'm not sure about the placement of "Libraries". I've not placed a Libraries folder in either PC or Arduino, since I figured there's a nonzero chance that I could write some library which interfaces between both rather than running isolated on one side. I'm also not sure if importing libraries into either Python/Arduino/Else will be easy if the libraries are all in a higher directory than the actual source.

I've read up on some guides on how to structure Python projects, and what I've got above seems to be roughly close inside the Python directory. How should I structure my project?

Comment: The answer to all "how do I organize my folders" questions is always the same: organize them in a way that makes sense to you, in a way that makes it easy to find things.

Comment: That is true. However, there are multiple ways of doing so that come to mind, so I was wondering what the tried and tested methods are.